# Add Json file contents to JsonObject in Java

Tags: json

I have a Json file `E:\\jsondemo.json` in disk. I want to create JSONObject in Java and add the contents of the json file to JSONObject. How it is possible?

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
```

After creating this objec, what should i do to read the file and put values in **jsonObject**
Thanks.

Comment: Which json library row you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform a file in a String using a function proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file):

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
  FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
  try {
    FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
    /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
    return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
  }
  finally {
    stream.close();
  }
}
```

After getting the string, you can transform it to a JSONObject with the following code:

```
String json = readFile("E:\\jsondemo.json");
JSONObject jo = null;
try {
jo = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the above example, I used [this library](http://www.json.org/java/index.html), very simple to learn. You can add values to your JSON object in this way:

```
jo.put("one", 1); 
jo.put("two", 2); 
jo.put("three", 3);
```

You can also create `JSONArray` objects, and add it to your `JSONObject`:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

ja.put("1");
ja.put("2");
ja.put("3");

jo.put("myArray", ja);
```